# what is the .NET equivalent of Java's ForkJoinTask<V>?

Tags: c#, .net, task

"Abstract base class for tasks that run within a ForkJoinPool. A ForkJoinTask is a thread-like entity that is much lighter weight than a normal thread. Huge numbers of tasks and subtasks may be hosted by a small number of actual threads in a ForkJoinPool, at the price of some usage limitations. "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) library?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Guavante, Task library was implemented by Fork Join parallelism. For example, you could have a look : [Parallel.For()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx), [Parallel.ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) . Both run multiple operations concurrently and wait all for them to complete.